# Sync between two SVN repositories using svnserve protocol

Tags: svn, synchronization, svnserve

We have two SVN repositories using svnserve (not Apache httpd), one onshore and another offshore.

Is it possible to create a reasonable synchronization between the two repositories? It is ok to have a Master/Slave configuration. Or are we forced to move to the more complex Apache server way of doing things? The reason I am asking is because it would cost time to change the current infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

For one-way synchronization you can try svnsync (it comes with command-line SVN client).

I've used it for local repositories and through Apache, so likely it will work through svnserve too.

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.tk.svnsync

Comment: Yes, I was planning on using svnsync. However, I remember reading that there would be some limitations using svnsync on svnserver. But I never really fully understood what the limitations are, even though I did find some information about it through google.